# MCV4 unicode encode error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, unicode, encode

I'm a new MVC4 users.
I building a CMS, everything is OK but I have a problem when my website have unicode content.

So, when I view it on browsers, everything is normal but when I use ViewSource Tools I see something like this:

Browser: 
**Khóa học AutoCAD**

ViewSource

```
<h4>Kh&#243;a học AutoCAD</h4>
```

In my .cshtml

```
<h4>@Html.Raw(Model.Title)</h4>
```

but the problem is still there
Here is my website: http://saigonpixel.com/vi/khoa-hoc-autocad
I try install an opensource MVC4 nopcommerce but it has same problem http://shop.saigonpixel.com

Please tell me how can I fix it?
Thanks a lot

PS: data in database are OK.
My layout charset is UTF-8

Comment: use @HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Model.Title)

Comment: Thanks I will try it now, Is there any other options to set encode for everything in my Views.

Comment: just check it and tell if it works???

Comment: I use @HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Model.Title) and in my view "Kh&#243;a học AutoCAD" => http://saigonpixel.com/vi/khoa-hoc-autocad

Comment: then use reverse of it @HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Title)...this will work...

Comment: It back to problem in main post... error in Viewsource